Is there a way to resend confirmation emails?
The title says it all.
There are several users who have registered but have yet to confirm their email addresses.
Based on their unique email domains, I suspect that the majority of unconfirmed accounts / email addresses have been created by bots.
I considered adding an expiration period to the confirmation email, but wanted to first contact those accounts prompting them to confirm their registrations.
I want to have an accurate picture of how many people are actively accessing, interacting with and using my site and feel that this is a good step.
I have taken a look at plugins but there are so many out there that it's hard to decide which one(s), if any, are suitable.
I have also looked at other questions on the WP Stack Exchange but am not sure if any existing questions cover what I need (my needs are, at present, more basic).
Either way some guidance would be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

All you would really need to do is trigger wp_new_user_notification for each user.  Notice you can filter the email message & subject with the wp_new_user_notification_email filter.
I made a very simple plugin ages ago for adding an action for this to the wordpress user list.  Really only made if for a client, no idea why I added this to the WP directory.  You can give it a try or browse the code, it's just a few lines: https://wordpress.org/plugins/re-welcome/

I am a total WordPress beginner here (although I am a computer scientist), so bear with me. I access WordPress via the site directly (it uses wp-admin), so I'm not sure how I would go about installing Re-Welcome. It prompts me to download it, whereas I have been used to installing plugins on the fly via the site's UI. In terms of filtering and triggering the function (wp_new_user_notification), how can I utilise that to then resend the confirmation email? Thanks again.

@Mus Just click "upload plugin" button to the right of the "Add Plugins" page title.  Or search for it in the search on the right.  Might be easier to find via author: andrewklimek
